# Linking problems of a ScalaFX project within Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse-juno, scalafx

This seems like the Final Pain in my journey of getting ScalaFX development up with Eclipse (Juno). In short, I'm able to compile and run a code in `sbt` but if I want debugging (would be nice) I need Eclipse.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to produce a small project that would exhibit this pain (I bump into other issues). If the snapshot below says anything to anyone on what might be wrong, you would have helped me tremendously.

The lines in question look like this (nothing remarkable in them):

```
  import scalafx.scene.shape.{Shape, Line, Arc}
    ..
  new Line{ 
    startX = p.x
    startY = p.y
    endX = tmp.x
    endY = tmp.y
  }
```

[image]

Here is my `.classpath` - in case that's where the problem is coming from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/scalafx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>

  <!-- 
  - Some reference to JavaFX seems to be needed (otherwise: "not found: object javafx")
  -->
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"></classpathentry>

  <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

All of this is on OS X, running Oracle Java 7u9 JDK (at least so I think!).

p.s. Eclipse is still slow and cumbersome compared to other IDE's I've worked with (Visual Studio, XCode), but is kind-of 'must' since the official [ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org) binding is working with it.

Comment: I'll leave this entry open, but moved on to IntelliJ to actually get a working Scala debugging environment up. Sorry, Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sbt, eclipse (indigo) and scalafx and it works.
The following compiles and works:

```
new Line{ 
startX = 10
startY = 10
endX = 20
endY = 20
}
```

If you want i can help you setup your environment.